# XP RDP to Windows 7 Can't Paste

Tags: remote-desktop, clipboard, cut-and-paste

I'm on Windows XP. I'm RDPing to a Windows 7 machine. I can cut and copy (ctrl-X or edit menu or right-click menu in various applications), but pasting just pastes nothing. (Regardless of if I paste by right-click or keyboard short-cut or right-click menu.)

Now what?

I tried shutting down and re-running rdpclip.exe, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes clipboard doesn't work for me too. Sometimes complains - no enough memory, sometimes not.

When close some programs (inside RDP) to release memory - starts working.

Comment: Brilliant. I closed some extra IDEs I had open (eep) and then it started pasting.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have some software, that hooks the clipboard, running. For example, I have TypePilot and it stops working properly if RDP session is running (the opposite scenario to yours). MS Office, IIRC, has some clipboard extension tool, which can conflict with RDP. There's plenty of other stuff listening for clipboard events. If one of those listeners is written incorrectly and it doesn't pass notifications further, RDP clipboard monitor just won't know that clipboard has anything to paste.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's nothing that's listening for the clipboard. How would I verify this?

Comment: @ashes999 try booting in Safe Mode with Network Support and RDP from there. Safe mode will exclude almost all autostart applications from being autostarted, so you will know if that is one of the applications that cause the problem.

Comment: It's possible that my Delphi IDE or my SQLYog did it (killing them made it work). +1 for the right direction, but ultimately not the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems siily but check to see if the clipboard checkbox is checked on the local resources tab??